# Is there a way to make comments looks different in Sublime 3?

Tags: comments, sublimetext3

I'd like to add some coloring to my comments so it's easier to find, or be able to group my comments by color so I know what comments are related to what process? From what I looked for, I couldn't find any specific packages.

Comment: you might check with the folks over at http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

you do this by going in to preference tab -> color scheme you can simply use predefined color scheme or you can also create your own

Comment: like be able to add coloring because right now all comments are just grayed out, so it'd be nice to make some blue and others red or whatnot

Comment: Re answered please check

Comment: http://www.freshtechtips.com/2014/01/create-custom-sublime-text-theme.html

Check this for your custom them